# What is a best practice approach for searching strings for pairs of characters?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to improve my coding skills and I have some code that will take an input sentence and search for any pairs of characters: 'th', 'ing' and 'ae' . The code does the following:

- Get the input string and convert to a list of characters
- Search the list to see if there are sequences like ["t","h",....] etc
- Insert into the list the a replacement (in this case "th")
- Replace the original search characters (i.e. "t", "h", ...) with "*"
- Rebuild the list excluding the "*"
- Return the list

So if my input was: "doing things with aero"

I would get back: ['d', 'o', 'ing', ' ', 'th', 'ing', 's', ' ', 'w', 'i', 'th', ' ', 'ae', 'r', 'o']

(FYI - I use this result to convert to another language in another programme)

This is the code:

```
def characters(a_list,a,b,c,d,e,f,g): # search for th, ae,ing
    """takes a list of characters and return an updated list joining certain character sequences """
    lista = [c for c in a_list.lower()]
    listb = []
    n = 0
    for i in lista:
        if i == a and lista[n+1] == b: # converts t + h into th
            i = "*"
            lista[n+1] = "*"
            listb.insert(n+1,f"{a}{b}")
        listb.append(i)
        n += 1
    n = 0
    listc = []
    for i in listb:
        if i == c and listb[n+1] == d: # converts a + e into ae
            i = "*"
            listb[n+1] = "*"
            listc.insert(n+1,f"{c}{d}")
        listc.append(i)
        n += 1
    n = 0
    listd = []
    for i in listc:
        if i == e and listc[n + 1] == f and listc[n + 2] == g: # converts i + n + g into ing
            i = "*"
            listc[n + 1] = "*"
            listc[n + 2] = "*"
            listd.insert(n + 1, f"{e}{f}{g}")
        listd.append(i)
        n += 1
    res = [n for n in listd if n != "*" ] # removes any *'s
    return res


input_string = "doing things with aero"
res = characters(input_string,"t","h","a","e","i","n","g")
print(res)
```

Is there a best practice / simpler method that I could use to search for characters in the list (or the original string) for pairs of characters and then change them as per my code.

Comment: I'd apply simple regular expression: `re.findall("(th|ae|ing|.)", "doing things with aero")`

Comment: Thanks Olvin, thats great the re finds the character sequences but not sure how to extract them to by resultant list.

Comment: `"".join(re.split("th|ae|ing", "doing things with aero"))` ?

Comment: thanks, thats great!